# Prove $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{(a+14)^2}{(b+4)^2}\geq \frac{3}{2} \sum\limits_{cyc} \left(\frac{a+14}{b+4}+\frac{b+4}{a+14}\right)-6$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, buffalo-way

**Problem.** For $a,b,c\geq 0.$ Prove that: $$\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{(a+14)^2}{(b+4)^2}\geq \frac{3}{2} \sum\limits_{cyc} \left(\frac{a+14}{b+4}+\frac{b+4}{a+14}\right)-6$$
I have a solution but it's not really nice.
The main idea is take $\frac{a+14}{b+4}=x,..$ and try to use the familiar result by Vo Quoc Ba Can.

You can find it in my [blog](https://t-t-h-n-e-w.blogspot.com/2020/11/problem-2.html). I'm looking for alternative solution now.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi downvote-er, why you do that?

Comment: Maybe you need to detail your answer and not put a link...(+1)

Comment: @ErikSatie thank you, I will add soon.